# Is it possible to pass wide NULL characters to ActiveX?

Tags: javascript, vbscript, com, activex, bho

```
[id(0x60020021), helpstring("method FileWriting")]
void FileWriting(
        [in] BSTR buffer);
```

I'd like to be able to pass a BSTR containing NULL characters to ActiveX control(This is not mine so i can't modify code).

There is no NULL filters in the code just using WriteFile through BSTR arguments but how could i pass Wide NULL(0x 00 00) to ActvieX ? Does it Possible?

```
obj.FileWriting(unescape("%u0041%u0042%u0043")) // working

obj.FileWriting(unescape("%u0041%u0000%u0043")) // not working, just "A"
```

Answer (score 0):

`unescape` handles `%u0000` correctly, `WScript.Echo`, MsgBox, and - perhaps - `.FileWriting` don't:

```
>> s = unescape("%u0041%u0000%u0042")
>> WScript.Echo s, Len(s), LenB(s)
>>
A 3 6
```

Answer (score -1):

BStr don't care if they have nulls in them. In VB or VBS `chr(43) & vbnull & chr(43)`. Everything is already unicode so no need to specify leading null bytes.

However nulls may cause problems with other programs or components that don't expect them.

Comment: vbNull is an Integer constant with a value of 1.